# Twilio Creating a 1:many relationship so that a single number reaches 2+ organizations

Tags: php, twilio, one-to-many

PHP
I can't seem to figure out how the calls should be routed now that we can assign a single number to multiple sites. I was thinking of using the callers site but then callers can be assigned multiple sites and then we're back to the same issue. Do you have any idea how else to go about this?
There is also an issue of what site the voicemail should be sorted into as a result of multiple sites having the same number.

This is for clinical trial sites.
Any suggestions of assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. So, what you want is how to handle one user to many calls in Twillo and PHP ?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'd love to help, but I think you've left off a lot of detail in this question regarding what you have already built and what you need to update it to. Could you update your question with an explanation of your existing application, the new feature you need to build, what you have tried so far to build that feature and what isn't working about it. Thanks.